# create a list filled with elements, length depends on given number

Tags: python

say I have a function which takes in a number e.g def function(number), I want to create a list filled with None's, and the length of the list is the number so say number = 4, list = [None, None, None, None]
is this possible?

Comment: This is a rather simple question, have you done any attempt at it? Such as using a simple loop or a more complex list comprehension?

Comment: You don't even need a loop for this.  This is a simple one-liner.  Look up with the multiplication operator `*` does for lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a few different ways.

Best way:

```py
number = 2
list1 = [None]*number
```

For Loop:

```py
number = 2
list1 = []
for _ in range(number):
    list1.append(None)
```

List Comprehension:

```py
number = 2
list1 = [None for _ in range(number)]
```